# self.tabBarController!.viewControllers returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with four different UIViews connected to it. The TabBarController is managed from the Controller.swift file, which looks like that

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Controller: UITabBarController {

var firebaseUser = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //let allVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
    //let SearchVC = allVC![1] as! SearchVC
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

However, the lines that are commented out lead to the error "...found nil while unwrapping optional.." (already getting allVC leads to the error)

How can I fix that error?

Comment: use `let allVC = self.viewControllers` as your class is a UITabBarViewController subclass

Comment: try just self.viewControllers

Comment: How is this Controller is initialized ? Using storyboard or programmatically ? If storyboard have u added VCs to Tab else if added programmatically where have you added viewControllers ??

Answer (score 9):

Use `let allVC = self.viewControllers` instead as your class is a `UITabBarViewController` subclass